# How to Scale a Image 1:1 in Apple Maps

Tags: swift, uiimageview, mapkit, mkmapview, scale

I need to scale an image/icon `1:1` in Apple Maps. Cannot find any Information about that topic on the Internet.

The Idea is to place a simple `jpg` as an `UIImageView` over the `MKMapView` . but if there is a other way please let me know

Just to be clear, I need to put the image in relation to the zoom level of the map. For example, show objects like a cat ;) or a tree in real size at the map. At the first step, the object should stay in the middle of the screen, so I can rotate and rearrange the map lying underneath. Later on a like to pin the object to the map.

Comment: can you please clarify your question and add some code snippets of your current attempt? Without more information it is hard to say what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Please provide further info, such as...  Do you mean add an image to the mapview such that it preserves its aspect ration?  Does the image need to be tied to a location on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with something like this:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        mapView.delegate = self

        draw()
    }

    func draw() {

        let region = mapView.region
        let center = region.center

        let pointsPerMeter = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(center.latitude)

        // Real-World-Object with 24 Meters length and 4 Meters width
        let objectLength = pointsPerMeter*24
        let objectWidth = pointsPerMeter*4
        let mapSize = MKMapSize.init(width: objectLength, height: objectWidth)
        let mapPoint = MKMapPoint.init(center)
        let objectRect = MKMapRect.init(origin: mapPoint, size: mapSize)

        // clear the map
        mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)

        // create image overlay from Real-World-Object
        let objectOverlay = ImageOverlay(image: UIImage(named: "nameOfYourImageAsset")!, rect: objectRect.offsetBy(dx: -objectLength/2 , dy: -objectWidth/2))

        // add overlay to map
        mapView.addOverlay(objectOverlay)

    }

}

// found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45989625/10878331
class ImageOverlay : NSObject, MKOverlay {
    let image:UIImage
    let boundingMapRect: MKMapRect
    let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(image: UIImage, rect: MKMapRect) {
        self.image = image
        self.boundingMapRect = rect
        self.coordinate = rect.origin.coordinate
    }
}

class ImageOverlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer {
    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {

        guard let overlay = self.overlay as? ImageOverlay else {
            return
        }

        let rect = self.rect(for: overlay.boundingMapRect)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        overlay.image.draw(in: rect)
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}
```

The Code isn't beauty yet, nor is it optimal, but it kind of works I guess. I assume that you already have your user location or any point so `mapView.region` has a valid value.

The Code is still in progress. I will try to put a simple UIImage on top of the map which i hopefully can put into context of the map. I guess I need to set mapView.isZoomEnabled = false for ease

Answer (score -2):

sir

YOu can jus simply drag UIImageTo your storyboard and set width or high to your image and then set aspect ratio 1:1 
(Just press control button and drag line from your image view to your image view and then press option to se that option)

Or you can do it programmatically

Have a nice day

Comment: sorry was a bit misleading. I need to put the image in relation to the zoom level of the map ... will update my question

Comment: You can show image depend on level of zoom on your MapView
Check that page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate